# How to set javax.ws.rs.Path annotation value from properties

Tags: java, web-services, jax-rs, jax-ws

I want to set `javax.ws.rs.Path` annotation value from properties file. **The purpose is not to make it configurable, rather the purpose is to separate the value from code.**

The following code works:

```
private final String path="my_path";

@GET
@Path(path)
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
public String wsdlRequest(@Context UriInfo uriInfo)
{
    ....
     ...
    ..
}
```

But the following does not:

```
private final String path=bundle.getString("PATH");
```

Comment: If the purpose is just to separate from code. put all these URL constants inside a class

Comment: I can't see how api becomes harder to follow by using constants. Even if it does, constants are sometimes necessary, so that configuration can be changed according to requirements without modifying the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess one cannot, since the value isn't available in the compile time.